# Cloudflare 404 and IUAM isn't working

Tags: cloudflare

I have Cloudflare connected to my website. All of my DNS records are accounted for with them and my nameservers are pointed to theirs. (It's been more than 24 hours) But the Cloudflare 404 errors and I'm Under Attack Mode doesn't seem to be working. It will only show the default 404 error message I made on my .htaccess file.

How can I fix this issue so my webpage will show the I'm Under Attack Message and Cloudflare 404 when activated?

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult to look at without the actual domain in question.

Possibilities:

1. The nameservers haven't updated to ours as of yet.
2. You signed up through a hosting partner & we can only provision a CNAME (like www) and you're checking against the A record for the root domain.